# Visual Studio 2017; argument of type "const wchar_t *" is incompatible with parameter of type "PWSTR" when /permissive is enabled

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am attempting to create a windows service in C++ (very new to it).

As a template, I am using this MDSN provided example: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/CppWindowsService-cacf4948

This project will not build if the Conformance Mode (/permissive-) flag is set to yes. It will error out with the following error

`E0167  argument of type "const wchar_t *" is incompatible with parameter of type "PWSTR`

when attempting to use the following function:

```
#define SERVICE_NAME             L"CppWindowsService"
        InstallService(
            SERVICE_NAME,               // Name of service - and so on for the other parameters
            );
```

Obviously, I could disable the flag, but it seems like a bad idea, as according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/permissive-standards-conformance?view=vs-2017, its purpose is to make my code more compliant.

Therefore, my question is as follows: how do I get around this error without disabling the /permissive flag?

Comment: Change the signature from `InstallService( PWSTR...` to `InstallService( PCWSTR...`.

Comment: Changing the signature results in a multitude of errors. PWSTR is used in multiple places throughout this sample service, so changing the InstallService signature breaks other functions.

Attempting to change all functions to use PCWSTR instead of PWSTR results in another error: "a value of type "PCWSTR" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "LPWSTR".

Comment: If you want to use the above flag, you just have to take time and fix the whole project. There is no way an expression like `PWSTR s = L"x";` will work.

Comment: Yeah, I agree. As per Nikita's advice, it does seem that I can initialize a wchar_t and use that. PWSTR is just everywhere though. I'll try replacing them all and see how I go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem that one of your arguments is const and another one is not. I don't know what InstallService is expected, but seems like it's expected const value. Try this.

Comment: That does not seem to be it. Irrespective of how I attempt to define my arguments, I can't get the compiler to accept them. If you have a moment, perhaps you could try? Download the solution in the link I provided, and enable the /permissive flag.

Comment: It does seem to be the case that I instead initialize a wchar_t, as per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/learnwin32/working-with-strings, I can pass that to PWSTR. That just means I have to replace a fair chunk of their code.

Comment: Yeah, passing wchar_t to all instances of PWSTR worked. The project built with the /permissive flag. This was indeed the solution. Thanks!