# How to post json data to api using winhttp in c++

Tags: c++, winapi, https

I need to post json data to api using c++. In the API, I also need to include `app_id` and `app_key` as header. Below is the code I am using:

```
std::wstring get_utf16(const std::string &str, int codepage)
{
    if (str.empty()) return std::wstring();
    int sz = MultiByteToWideChar(codepage, 0, &str[0], (int)str.size(), 0, 0);
    std::wstring res(sz, 0);
    MultiByteToWideChar(codepage, 0, &str[0], (int)str.size(), &res[0], sz);
    return res;
}

LPCWSTR additionalHeaders = L"Content-Type: application/json\r\n" + L"app_id: 7ty44" + L"app_key: e36ff19de5623";
DWORD headersLength = -1;

string HttpsWebRequestPost(string domain, string url, string dat)
{
    //Extra
    LPSTR  data = const_cast<char *>(dat.c_str());;
    DWORD data_len = strlen(data);


    wstring sdomain = get_utf16(domain, CP_UTF8);
    wstring surl = get_utf16(url, CP_UTF8);
    string response;

    DWORD dwSize = 0;
    DWORD dwDownloaded = 0;
    LPSTR pszOutBuffer;
    BOOL  bResults = FALSE;
    HINTERNET  hSession = NULL,
        hConnect = NULL,
        hRequest = NULL;

    // Use WinHttpOpen to obtain a session handle.
    hSession = WinHttpOpen(L"WinHTTP Example/1.0",
        WINHTTP_ACCESS_TYPE_DEFAULT_PROXY,
        WINHTTP_NO_PROXY_NAME,
        WINHTTP_NO_PROXY_BYPASS, 0);

    // Specify an HTTP server.
    if (hSession)
        hConnect = WinHttpConnect(hSession, sdomain.c_str(),
            INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTP_PORT, 0);

    // Create an HTTP request handle.
    if (hConnect)
        hRequest = WinHttpOpenRequest(hConnect, L"POST", surl.c_str(),
            NULL, WINHTTP_NO_REFERER,
            WINHTTP_DEFAULT_ACCEPT_TYPES,
            0);

    // Send a request.
    if (hRequest)
        bResults = WinHttpSendRequest(hRequest,
            additionalHeaders,
            headersLength,
            (LPVOID)data,
            data_len,
            data_len,
            0);

    // End the request.
    if (bResults)
        bResults = WinHttpReceiveResponse(hRequest, NULL);

    // Keep checking for data until there is nothing left.
    if (bResults)
    {
        do
        {
            // Check for available data.
            dwSize = 0;
            if (!WinHttpQueryDataAvailable(hRequest, &dwSize))
                printf("Error %u in WinHttpQueryDataAvailable.\n",
                    GetLastError());

            // Allocate space for the buffer.
            pszOutBuffer = new char[dwSize + 1];
            if (!pszOutBuffer)
            {
                printf("Out of memory\n");
                dwSize = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                // Read the data.
                ZeroMemory(pszOutBuffer, dwSize + 1);

                if (!WinHttpReadData(hRequest, (LPVOID)pszOutBuffer,
                    dwSize, &dwDownloaded))
                    printf("Error %u in WinHttpReadData.\n", GetLastError());
                else
                    //printf("%s", pszOutBuffer);
                    response = response + string(pszOutBuffer);
                // Free the memory allocated to the buffer.
                delete[] pszOutBuffer;
            }
        } while (dwSize > 0);
    }

    // Report any errors.
    if (!bResults)
        printf("Error %d has occurred.\n", GetLastError());

    // Close any open handles.
    if (hRequest) WinHttpCloseHandle(hRequest);
    if (hConnect) WinHttpCloseHandle(hConnect);
    if (hSession) WinHttpCloseHandle(hSession);

    return response;

}
```

I have include the `app_id` and `app_key` in `additional headers` but not sure if this is the correct way to do it or not. Also how can I call it by passing the json data which I need to send. I did not find any good working example for this. Thanks

Comment: Is there a reason not to use WinInet instead of WinHTTP?

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis I didnt knew about `WinInet `. Let me google this. I come from python background and very new to c++. Thanks

Comment: You can take a look to my [REST library](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1163475/Take-a-REST-A-Windows-Cplusplus-library-for-quick), part of my  [RGF library](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5061520/RGF-A-Save-Open-dialog-box-with-cloud-capabilities)

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis Can you give short example on how to use it

Comment: @SAndrew: In C++ and Python, core programming principles are similar enough. Importantly, in both the task of creating Json is distinct from the task of HTTP POST'ing text. For the WinHTTP part, you might be sending "Hello, World" - it doesn't care.

Comment: If you cannot make it to work, I can post one of my WinHHTP wrapper functions that I used in a Freeware, and that can be tested on testing sites like [Dummy Rest API Example](http://dummy.restapiexample.com/)

Comment: @Castorix Yes please can you post a working example. I am struggling to get it working. Thanks

Comment: If you are targeting Windows 10 (and up), consider using the pre-built [HttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/networking/httpclient). It'll literally condense the code you have to write down to a handful of lines of code. When using [C++/WinRT](https://aka.ms/cppwinrt), you don't have to write your encoding conversions either (see [String handling in C++/WinRT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/strings)).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the discussion with "S Andrew", a Win32 Console App to test GET/POST with WinHTTP, using a wrapper function used in an old freeware

Requests tested with the site [www.dummy.restapiexample.com](http://www.dummy.restapiexample.com)

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

#include <Winhttp.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "Winhttp")

#include <Shlwapi.h> // SHRegGetValue
#pragma comment(lib, "Shlwapi")

#define HTTP_TIMEOUT 15000
HINTERNET hOpen, hOpenProxy;
void GetProxy(WCHAR* sProxyName);
DWORD WinHTTPRequest(LPCTSTR pServerName, LPCTSTR pRequest, WCHAR* sCommand, LPVOID pPostData, int nPostDataLength, LPCWSTR pwszHeaders, char **dataOut, int *nRead, WCHAR **dataHeaderOut, BOOL bTestProxy, BOOL bSecure, WCHAR* wsRedirect, DWORD *dwReturnStatus);
WCHAR g_wsCurrentProxy[255] = L"";

int main()
{
    hOpen = WinHttpOpen(L"Test", WINHTTP_ACCESS_TYPE_DEFAULT_PROXY, WINHTTP_NO_PROXY_NAME,  WINHTTP_NO_PROXY_BYPASS, 0);
    WinHttpSetTimeouts(hOpen, HTTP_TIMEOUT, HTTP_TIMEOUT, HTTP_TIMEOUT, HTTP_TIMEOUT);

    WCHAR wsHostName[MAX_PATH] = L"www.dummy.restapiexample.com";
    WCHAR wsURLPathGet[MAX_PATH] = L"/api/v1/employees";
    WCHAR wsURLPathPost[MAX_PATH] = L"/api/v1/create";
    char sPostData[500] = "{\"name\":\"Test Unique Name 1\",\"salary\":\"123456\",\"age\":\"18\"}";

    char *sHTTPData = NULL;
    int nDataRead = 0;
    WCHAR *wsDataHeader = NULL;
    WCHAR wsRedirect[2048 + 32 + 3]; // INTERNET_MAX_URL_LENGTH
    DWORD dwStatus = 0;

    WCHAR wsAdditionalHeaders[1024] = L"";
    lstrcpy(wsAdditionalHeaders,
        L"Accept: application/json\r\n"
        L"Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n"
        //L"Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br\r\n");
        L"Accept-Encoding: txt\r\n");

    printf("Before first GET - Type a key\n");
    _getch();
    DWORD dwReturn = WinHTTPRequest(wsHostName, wsURLPathGet, L"GET", WINHTTP_NO_REQUEST_DATA, NULL, wsAdditionalHeaders, &sHTTPData, &nDataRead, &wsDataHeader, 0, 0, wsRedirect, &dwStatus);
    if (dwStatus == 0)
        printf(sHTTPData);
    else
        printf("Error Status : [%d]\n", dwStatus);
    if (sHTTPData)
        delete[] sHTTPData;
    if (wsDataHeader)
        delete[] wsDataHeader;

    printf("\n\nBefore POST - Type a key\n");
    _getch();
    dwReturn = WinHTTPRequest(wsHostName, wsURLPathPost, L"POST", sPostData, NULL, wsAdditionalHeaders, &sHTTPData, &nDataRead, &wsDataHeader, 0, 0, wsRedirect, &dwStatus);
    if (dwStatus == 0)
        printf(sHTTPData);
    else
        printf("Error Status : [%d]\n", dwStatus);
    if (sHTTPData)
        delete[] sHTTPData;
    if (wsDataHeader)
        delete[] wsDataHeader;

    printf("\n\nBefore second GET - Type a key\n");
    _getch();
    dwReturn = WinHTTPRequest(wsHostName, wsURLPathGet, L"GET", WINHTTP_NO_REQUEST_DATA, NULL, wsAdditionalHeaders, &sHTTPData, &nDataRead, &wsDataHeader, 0, 0, wsRedirect, &dwStatus);
    if (dwStatus == 0)
        printf(sHTTPData);
    else
        printf("Error Status : [%d]\n", dwStatus);
    if (sHTTPData)
        delete[] sHTTPData;
    if (wsDataHeader)
        delete[] wsDataHeader;

    printf("\n\nEND - Type a key\n");
    _getch();
    if (hOpen)
        WinHttpCloseHandle(hOpen);
    if (hOpenProxy)
        WinHttpCloseHandle(hOpenProxy);
    return 0;
}

void GetProxy(WCHAR* sProxyName)
{
    lstrcpy(sProxyName, L"");
    unsigned long nBufferSize = 4096;
    WCHAR wszBuf[4096] = { 0 };
    WINHTTP_PROXY_INFO* pInfo = (WINHTTP_PROXY_INFO*)wszBuf;
    if (WinHttpQueryOption(NULL, WINHTTP_OPTION_PROXY, pInfo, &nBufferSize))
    {
        if (pInfo->dwAccessType == WINHTTP_OPTION_PROXY)
        {
            WCHAR wsKey[MAX_PATH] = L"Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Internet Settings";
            WCHAR wsValue[MAX_PATH] = L"ProxyEnable";
            DWORD dwValue = (DWORD)FALSE;
            DWORD dwSize = sizeof(dwValue);
            LONG nStatus = SHRegGetValue(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, wsKey, wsValue, SRRF_RT_DWORD, NULL, &dwValue, &dwSize);            
            if ((nStatus == ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND) || (nStatus == ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND))
                nStatus = SHRegGetValue(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, wsKey, wsValue, SRRF_RT_DWORD, NULL, &dwValue, &dwSize);
            if (nStatus != ERROR_SUCCESS)
                dwValue = FALSE;
            if (dwValue)
                lstrcpy(sProxyName, pInfo->lpszProxy);
        }
    }
}

DWORD WinHTTPRequest(LPCTSTR pServerName, LPCTSTR pRequest, WCHAR* sCommand, LPVOID pPostData, int nPostDataLength, LPCWSTR pwszHeaders, char **dataOut, int *nRead, WCHAR **dataHeaderOut, BOOL bTestProxy, BOOL bSecure, WCHAR* wsRedirect, DWORD *dwReturnStatus)
{
    HINTERNET hCurrentOpen = NULL;
    if (bTestProxy)
    {
        WCHAR sProxy[255] = L"";
        GetProxy(sProxy);
        if (lstrcmp(sProxy, L"") == 0)
            hCurrentOpen = hOpen;
        else if (lstrcmp(sProxy, g_wsCurrentProxy) != 0)
        {
            if (hOpenProxy)
                WinHttpCloseHandle(hOpenProxy);
            hOpenProxy = WinHttpOpen(L"Test", WINHTTP_ACCESS_TYPE_NAMED_PROXY, sProxy, NULL, 0/*INTERNET_FLAG_ASYNC*/);
            lstrcpy(g_wsCurrentProxy, sProxy);
            hCurrentOpen = hOpenProxy;
        }
        else
            hCurrentOpen = hOpenProxy;
    }
    else
        hCurrentOpen = hOpen;

    HINTERNET hConnect = NULL;
    if (bSecure)
        hConnect = WinHttpConnect(hCurrentOpen, pServerName, INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTPS_PORT, 0);
    else
        hConnect = WinHttpConnect(hCurrentOpen, pServerName, INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTP_PORT, 0);

    if (!hConnect)
    {
        DWORD dwError = GetLastError();
        return dwError;
    }

    DWORD dwFlags;
    if (bSecure)
        dwFlags = WINHTTP_FLAG_SECURE | WINHTTP_FLAG_REFRESH;
    else
        dwFlags = WINHTTP_FLAG_REFRESH; 

    HINTERNET hRequest = WinHttpOpenRequest(hConnect, sCommand, pRequest, NULL, WINHTTP_NO_REFERER, WINHTTP_DEFAULT_ACCEPT_TYPES, dwFlags);
    if (!hRequest)
    {
        DWORD dwError = GetLastError();
        WinHttpCloseHandle(hConnect);
        return dwError;
    }

    WinHttpAddRequestHeaders(hRequest, pwszHeaders, -1, WINHTTP_ADDREQ_FLAG_ADD);
    int nLengthPostData;
    if (nPostDataLength == NULL)
    {
        if (pPostData)
            nLengthPostData = strlen((char*)pPostData);
        else
            nLengthPostData = 0;
    }
    else
        nLengthPostData = nPostDataLength;

    BOOL bSuccess;
    if (wsRedirect != NULL)
    {
        DWORD dwOption;
        DWORD dwOptionSize;
        dwOption = WINHTTP_OPTION_REDIRECT_POLICY_NEVER;
        dwOptionSize = sizeof(DWORD);
        bSuccess = WinHttpSetOption(hRequest, WINHTTP_OPTION_REDIRECT_POLICY, (LPVOID)&dwOption, dwOptionSize);
        DWORD dwOptionValue = WINHTTP_DISABLE_REDIRECTS;
        bSuccess = WinHttpSetOption(hRequest, WINHTTP_OPTION_DISABLE_FEATURE, &dwOptionValue, sizeof(dwOptionValue));
    }   
    BOOL b = WinHttpSendRequest(hRequest, WINHTTP_NO_ADDITIONAL_HEADERS, 0, pPostData, pPostData == NULL ? 0 : nLengthPostData, nLengthPostData, 0 );
    if (!b)
    {
        DWORD dwError = GetLastError();
        WinHttpCloseHandle(hConnect);
        WinHttpCloseHandle(hRequest);
        return dwError;
    }
    WinHttpReceiveResponse( hRequest, NULL);
    DWORD dwStatus = 0;
    DWORD dwStatusSize = sizeof(DWORD);
    if (WinHttpQueryHeaders(hRequest, WINHTTP_QUERY_STATUS_CODE | WINHTTP_QUERY_FLAG_NUMBER, NULL, &dwStatus, &dwStatusSize, NULL))
    {
        if (HTTP_STATUS_REDIRECT == dwStatus || HTTP_STATUS_MOVED == dwStatus)
        {
            DWORD dwSize;
            WinHttpQueryHeaders(hRequest, WINHTTP_QUERY_LOCATION, WINHTTP_HEADER_NAME_BY_INDEX, NULL, &dwSize, WINHTTP_NO_HEADER_INDEX);
            if (GetLastError() != ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER)
                return 500;
            LPWSTR pwsRedirectURL = new WCHAR[dwSize];
            bSuccess = WinHttpQueryHeaders(hRequest, WINHTTP_QUERY_LOCATION, WINHTTP_HEADER_NAME_BY_INDEX, pwsRedirectURL, &dwSize, WINHTTP_NO_HEADER_INDEX);
            if (!bSuccess)
                return 500;
            if (wsRedirect != NULL)
                lstrcpy(wsRedirect, pwsRedirectURL);
            if (dwReturnStatus != NULL)
                *dwReturnStatus = dwStatus;
            delete[] pwsRedirectURL;
        }
        else if (dwStatus != HTTP_STATUS_OK && dwStatus != HTTP_STATUS_BAD_REQUEST && dwStatus != HTTP_STATUS_CREATED)
        {
            DWORD dwError = GetLastError();
            WinHttpCloseHandle(hConnect);
            WinHttpCloseHandle(hRequest);
            if (dwReturnStatus != NULL)
                *dwReturnStatus = dwStatus;
            return dwError;
        }
    }
    if (dataHeaderOut != NULL)
    {
        DWORD dwSize = 0;
        WCHAR *pOutBuffer = NULL;
        if (!WinHttpQueryHeaders(hRequest,WINHTTP_QUERY_RAW_HEADERS_CRLF, WINHTTP_HEADER_NAME_BY_INDEX, NULL, &dwSize, WINHTTP_NO_HEADER_INDEX))
        {
            DWORD dwErr = GetLastError();
            if (dwErr != ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER)
            {
                DWORD dwError = GetLastError();
                WinHttpCloseHandle(hConnect);
                WinHttpCloseHandle(hRequest);
                return dwError;
            }
        }
        pOutBuffer = new WCHAR[dwSize];
        if (WinHttpQueryHeaders(hRequest,WINHTTP_QUERY_RAW_HEADERS_CRLF,WINHTTP_HEADER_NAME_BY_INDEX, pOutBuffer, &dwSize, WINHTTP_NO_HEADER_INDEX))
        {
            pOutBuffer[dwSize] = '\0';
            *dataHeaderOut = (WCHAR*)pOutBuffer;
        }       
        //delete[] pOutBuffer;
    }

    char *sReadBuffer = NULL;
    DWORD nTotalRead = 0;
    DWORD nToRead = 0;
    DWORD nBytesRead = 0;
    do {
        if (!WinHttpQueryDataAvailable(hRequest, &nToRead))
            break;
        if (nToRead == 0)
            break;
        sReadBuffer = (char*)((sReadBuffer == NULL) ? malloc(nToRead) : realloc(sReadBuffer, nTotalRead + nToRead + 1));
        if (WinHttpReadData(hRequest, sReadBuffer + nTotalRead, nToRead, &nBytesRead))
        {
            nTotalRead += nBytesRead;
        }
    } while (nToRead > 0);
    if (sReadBuffer != NULL && nTotalRead > 0)
    {
        {
            char *sBuffer = new char[nTotalRead + 1];
            memcpy(sBuffer, sReadBuffer, nTotalRead + 1);
            sBuffer[nTotalRead] = '\0';
            *dataOut = sBuffer;
        }
        free(sReadBuffer);
    }

    *nRead = nTotalRead;
    WinHttpCloseHandle(hConnect);
    WinHttpCloseHandle(hRequest);
    return ERROR_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: I am getting this error `Error (active) E0167 argument of type "const wchar_t *" is incompatible with parameter of type "WCHAR *"` at every `L("GET)` and `L("POST")`

Comment: You can see threads like [Visual Studio 2017; argument of type “const wchar_t *” is incompatible with parameter of type “PWSTR” when /permissive is enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52896743/visual-studio-2017-argument-of-type-const-wchar-t-is-incompatible-with-para) (I use VS 2015)

Comment: Thanks I got it working. Just a quick question, how can we pass in Json data instead of `char sPostData[500]`. Thanks

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "Json data". The text I hardcoded in _sPostData_ is a basic Json string, like in the [Create sample](http://www.dummy.restapiexample.com/create)

Comment: I was able to use this code, but I had to change one thing for posting json data.  The header "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" needed to be changed to "Content-Type: application/json"

Answer (score 5):

`L"Content-Type: application/json\r\n" + L"app_id: 7ty44" + L"app_key: e36ff19de5623"`

That's not going to work. C++ does have a string type, but you're using string *literals* here. Thes have the type `wchar_t[LENGTH]`, i.e. they're fixed-with arrays of characters. And unlike the string type, these do not have `operator+`.

Instead, adjacent string literals will be concatenated by the compiler:

```
LPCWSTR additionalHeaders = 
    L"Content-Type: application/json\r\n"
    L"app_id: 7ty44\r\n"
    L"app_key: e36ff19de5623\r\n"; // << Only this line has a ;
```

Comment: Thanks. Does it also accepts json data which is to be posted. I can see string only.

Comment: @SAndrew: I commented on the question itself that you seem to have a challenge with partitioning your problems. This answer refers to the HTTP headers, and fixes the problem you had with `+`. It does not do anything about the HTTP body, which is where the actual JSON goes.

Comment: So there is no way of passing the json data. In my question I have also asked about passing json data while calling the api

Comment: Correct, there is no way to pass the JSON data **in the HTTP header**. You're correctly passing it as "optional data" in `WinHttpSendRequest`

Comment: Applogies if I asked something wrong but I wanted to know how can we pass json data as body to api instead of header